# jaydebeapi: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, python, jdbc, jaydebeapi

Running into below error when trying to run the following:

```
In [1]: import jaydebeapi

In [2]: conn = jaydebeapi.connect("org.netezza.Driver",
   ...:                           "jdbc:netezza://{Server}:{Port}/{DB}",
   ...:                            {'user': "{user}", 'password': "{pass}"},
   ...:                             "<path_to_driver.jar>")

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007ff215485f2c, pid=11353, tid=0x00007ff2528d6740
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_131-b11) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  java.security.AccessControlContext.<clinit>()V+0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /<path_to_log>/hs_err_pid11353.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted
```